# Is it possible to get hashes of individual 16KB blocks from a v2 torrent file? v1?

Tags: bittorrent, monotorrent

I want to cache torrent blocks based on their content hash. In v2 instead of simple block hashes there's a merkle tree, whose exact composition I can't quite comprehend.

I am working with MonoTorrent library, and it has `IPieceHashes.GetHash(hashIndex)` function where `hashIndex` varies from from 0 to piece count - 1. But there's no similar function to get hash of individual blocks (in case piece consists of multiple blocks).

Answer (score -1):

In v2 the easiest way to obtain them is to download a whole piece instead of a chunk, compute the leaf hashes from the data you have received and then verify the leaf hashes against the `piece layers` in the `.torrent` metadata file.
Alternatively you can `hash request` the leaf hashes while downloading chunks from a peer and verify them against the file root.
Both approaches involve merkle tree verification.

In v1 you're limited to downloading a whole piece and verifying its hash against the `pieces` list in the metadata file.

Comment: The question is about getting hashes of 16 KiB chunks directly from the .torrent file without downloading anything else.

Comment: Then you can't. You need either the data itself or another peer to talk to.